# How to make a regex that matches the character input with methods and calls it?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have methods like this-

```
void a(){
//Some statements here
}
void b(){
//Some statements here
}
void c(){
//some statements here
}
```

And I am taking input like this-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = sc.next();
```

And if the input is "ac" then how can I separate the input and  call the a() and c() methods by regex?

Comment: Extract `a` and `c` from user input and put it into a variable, say `userInput`. Then use a simple `if(userInput.equals("a") a(); else if(userInput.equals("b") b();...`. If there are a lot of functions to call, use `switch`

Comment: If the methods are named `abc`, `a` and `bc`, how do you decide which one(s) to call?

Comment: Also, do you expect to know all the methods that may be called this way, or do you want to be able to call any method the class has?

Comment: The real thing is: what problem are you trying to solve here? Is it just for education, or a real problem you intend to solve?

Comment: @GhostCat i am trying to make a program that inputs your name and print it in patterns and the methods like a(),b() etc. contains the code that prints the pattern but it is only possible when the program knows what are your inputs

Comment: Why do you insist on using regex? Are other options allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `switch` statement here:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = sc.next();
String[] methods = name.split("\\|");

for (String method : methods) {
    switch(method) {
        case "a":
            a();
            break;

        case "c":
            c();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("No method " + method + "() is known to exist");
            break;
    }
}
```

I have made one significant design change here.  I assume that you will enter the method names as pipe-separated.  For example, if you wanted to call `a()` and `c()`, in that order, you would enter `a|c` into the scanner.  Pipe `|` is not allowed in Java method names as far as I know, so it is a good candidate for a separator.

There might be a way to try to directly invoke a method using the string name, e.g. using reflection, but then we would have to worry about a method potentially not existing.  The above `case` statement avoids this from happening.

Comment: @GhostCat I mean...yuck...how many times have you actually used that at work?  Personally, I can count on one hand the number of times.

Comment: You need reflection when you do framework'ish things. And well, I am using the Apache Equals/HashCode Builder here and there, and they are reflection based. And Gson. And and and ... but myself: rarely ;-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Everytime I use Spring. IMO the question isn't specific enough so I can't tell whether reflection would make sense in this case. Reflection can be a nightmare, but so can a switch with 150 branches and need to add one everytime you add a method to *another* part of your codebase.

Comment: thanks for answering but i have to make methods up to 'z' that means i have to make cases up to 'z'. do you have any short code for doing so? well your code is amazing but i want to know that i have to make cases up to 'z' or is there any short code that can solve the problem

Comment: @newbieprogrammer The only way I know to call a method "automatically" would be to use reflection and just invoke the method by string name.  But, this is a bunch of work, and you would then need to handle the case where a user enters a method which does not exist.  My current answer might fit better for your purpose.

Comment: there is a problem i am giving input ac and it showing the statement given in the default instead calling the methods a() and c()

Comment: Read my answer carefully.  You need to input `a|c`.

Comment: thanks for your answer i just changed foreach loop to for loop which iterates over each character and calls the method thank you so much i was able to do this because of you i was thinking to use regex but it seems very hard since i have never used it so once again thanks

Comment: Why to change the requirement and expect different input? You can split on empty string...

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak A good general answer doesn't assume that method names are single letters.  How many code bases in real life have you seen where this is the case?  And, if you want to assume single letters, it would be more efficient to just use `String#toCharArray` than splitting with a regex engine.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen methods don't have to be a single character, but the input being single character is actually very common for input parameters (like `ls -al`).

Comment: Another question to ask NewbieProgrammer would be why use a Regular-Expression for the specific problem?  It would be a lot easier to read and write a simple `for (char c : inputString) switch(c) { case ... case }` than using a **Reg-Ex** at all!

Answer (score 1):

I think Tim Biegeleisen's answer solves the problem. Here is an alternate solution that might be of some use.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FunctionMap {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, java.lang.Runnable> methodMap = new HashMap<>();

        //If methods are similar, define them all in one fell swoop
        for(char i ='a'; i<='y'; i++) {
            final char finalI = i;
            methodMap.put(i,
                    () -> System.out.println("Boring method " + finalI + " invoked"));
        }

        //If they are not similar, define them separately.
        methodMap.put('z',
                () -> System.out.println("This method is very different!"));

        String userInput = "abvdxz";
        for(char s: userInput.toCharArray())
            methodMap.get(s).run();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Method a invoked
Method b invoked
Method v invoked
Method d invoked
Method x invoked
This method is very different!
```

The idea is you can put your functions in a map as you are defining them (it can be even simpler if functions are similar). For reading and parsing user input, I suggest using the approach in Tim Biegeleisen's answer. Here I assume that has already been done and focus on trying to avoid having a `switch` statement.

Comment: thanks jrook for your reply well in Tim's solution the input should be like this "a|b" but i want the input like this "ab" anyways i got the solution and thanks again

Comment: @newbieprogrammer:     There is a reason Tim has suggested `|` for input separation. It will serve you well to heed that reason mentioned in the answer. Anyway, I edited my answer to suit it to single-character method names.

Comment: thanks but i can't vote your answer because my reputation is less than 15 stackoverflow lol